# Как увеличить значение атрибута класса, при каждом новом вызове объекта класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется класс:

```
class Server:
    ip = 1
```

Как можно увеличить значение атрибута класса при каждом новом вызове объекта класса, на единицу?

```
sv_from = Server()
sv_from2 = Server()
```

Например создаю первый объект класса, у него **ip** == 1, а вот второй объект класса должен увеличить **ip** на единицу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обычно это делают в методе `__init__`:

```
class Server:
    ip = 1
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip = Server.ip # важно сначала присвоить текущее...
        Server.ip += 1 # ...а потом уже увеличивать идентификатор

sv_from = Server()
sv_from2 = Server()

print(sv_from.ip)
print(sv_from2.ip)
```

Вывод:

```
1
2
```

Comment: У меня вопрос, почему когда я ставлю ip 0, то первый ip так и остается 0, хотя должен увеличиваться на 1

Comment: @Kazak вы можете поменять местами закоментированные строки и будет `1`

Comment: @Kazak ну а остается он, потому что `Server.ip` - классовая переменная, а не конкретного объекта (`self.ip`) и друг от друга они никак не зависят